# Dynamically Changing Connection String of Entity Framework DB Connection

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am using MVC5 and Entity Framework 6.  I need to do a dual-load of data into two different databases, so I need to dynamically change the connection of the DBContext before I do the second load.

In doing some research, I'm seeing a lot of people saying that you can just pass the Connection String as a parameter of the DBContext.

However, in my case, it does not appear to have any overloads that accept any parameters, and when I inspect the DBContext, it does not have a constructor that accepts any parameters.

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
```

Is this a depreciated constructor in newer versions of the Entity Framework?  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if each database had its own context.

So, I would recommend you to have two classes extending DbContext and you would use it as needed.

Since we are talking about different databases, the schema can change, the mapping can be different and so on.

If you have to retrieve the same kind of data, you could take advantage of polymorphism and avoid lots of conditionals in your code.

Answer (score 0):

to have the parameter I think you need to add the connection string to the method and use as many connection as you want.

`public Entities(string connectionNameInYourWebConfig = "yourDefaultName") : 
base($"name={connectionNameInYourWebConfig}")
    {
    }`

I guess because in your case this might be occasionaly I added the default connection to the parameter. I hope this answer your question, Cheers

Comment: Would this change to the constructor revert back every time I did an update to our edmx?

Comment: If you using the mapping from EF you could directly go to you file which called "yourContainerName.context.tt" and find this bit of code (without tests I added) : public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string test = "test")
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>" + test)
  and add this string connectionStringParam = "yourConnectionName" and don't forget to add it to the base :D